# OpenID Connect: Possible to launch web page from application and automatically log in user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We have a desktop application that requires the user to login. We're using OIDC (Auth code with PKCE) to do the login. I'd really like to be able to launch a browser and go to our website and log the user in automatically without resorting to anything dodgy.

From my understanding of OpenID Connect, I'm pretty sure this can't be done. Am I correct, or is there a mechanism I've missed?

Comment: What's the reason you are pretty sure it can't be done? I'm not aware of anything in OIDC preventing that...

Comment: What could I pass to the browser that would automatically authenticate the user?

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine if the user has a valid session cookie with the OpenID Provider (OP) in the browser. There's no need to send something *to* the browser, as the user is already authenticated there.

When subsequently your native app requests authorization, the OP can authenticate the user based on the existing session, provided that request parameters like `prompt`, `max_age` and `acr_values` allow for that.

Comment: "This should work fine if the user has a valid session cookie with the OpenID Provider (OP) in the browser."
But in the example where they login using my native application, they don't initially have a valid session cookie in the browser (unless they'd already logged in using their browser); that's the scenario I'd like to fix.

Comment: I see. Perhaps if your app is in possession of a valid ID Token, it could send that back to the OpenID Provider (OP) as an `id_token_hint` for the OP to sign the user in.